# Can I install Ubuntu over Windows 8 in CSM mode?

Tags: system-installation

I currently have a Samsung Series 3 (355V4C/356V4C/344V4C/355V4C) that came with Windows 8 already installed on the system. Would it be possible and error-free to install Ubuntu 13.10 on this laptop if I have "Fast Boot", and "Secure Boot" set to disabled and select CSM?

I plan to completely get rid of Windows 8 and just use Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of installing, when it asks you where to install, there will be three options:

- Install Ubuntu alongside Windows
- Replace Windows and install Ubuntu
- Something Else

Choose the second option to completely remove Windows. That's it.

One more piece of advice is to not use 13.10 -- it's buggy and you will encounter many bugs.  Instead of 13.10, go for 13.04 -- it's somehow more stable than 13.10.

Comment: If you are going to recommend other versions, you might mention that support for 13.04 ends in January.